# How to remove an item in an array of object where key value is

Tags: javascript

I have the following object of arrays:

```
{
    "Custom Mexico": [
        {
            "cursor": "eyJsYXNasdf0LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiQWd1YXNjYWxpZW50ZXMgTGljZW5zZSBQbGF0ZSBIYXQifQ==",
            "node": {
                "id": "gid://shopify/Product/993sasd5454",
                "title": "Aguascalientes License Plate Hat"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor": "eyJsYXN0X2lkIasdfYWx1ZSI6IkJhamEgQ2FsaWZvcm5pYSBMaWNlbnNlIFBsYXRlIEhhdCJ9",
            "node": {
                "id": "gid://shopify/Product/18asdf9144",
                "title": "Baja California License Plate Hat"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor": "eyJsYXN0X2asdf3MTYwLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiQmFqYSBDYWxpZm9ybmlhIFN1ciBMaWNlbnNlIFBsYXRlIEhhdCJ9",
            "node": {
                "id": "gid://shopify/Product/13asdf67160",
                "title": "Baja California Sur License Plate Hat"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Mexico Stuff": [
        {
            "cursor": "eyJsYXN0asdfjQxNTExNTEyLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMCJ9",
            "node": {
                "id": "gid://shopify/Product/73sdf11512",
                "title": "Tamaulipas Metal License Plate"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor": "eyJsYXN0X2lkIjasdfNzQ0LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMCJ9",
            "node": {
                "id": "gid://shopify/Product/736asdf78744",
                "title": "Hidalgo Metal License Plate"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor": "eyJsYXNasdfA4LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMCJ9",
            "node": {
                "id": "gid://shopify/Product/736asdf08",
                "title": "Guanajuato Metal License Plate"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to return the exact same structure but removing an item if it's in the array:

```
// where products is the object above:
  const item = "gid://shopify/Product/13s345f67160";
  const listCopy = structuredClone(products);

  const updatedList = Object.keys(listCopy).map(elGroup => {
    return listCopy[elGroup].filter(obj => obj.node.id != item);
  })
```

This returns the array but omits the name of the Object in example "Custom Mexico".
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: by "an item if it's in the array:" do you mean to only get unique values or is "array" something not IN the question at present? `item` is undefined here in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly mutate the copy and use that afterward.

```js
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(listCopy))
    listCopy[k] = v.filter(obj => obj.node.id != item);
// use listCopy now
```

Alternatively, filter the entries and use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build the object again. There is no need to make a copy with `structuredClone` in this case.

```js
const updatedList = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(products).map(([k, v]) => [k, v.filter(obj => obj.node.id != item)])
);
```

Comment: See the second solution working here: https://jsfiddle.net/q45kztvm/

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeItem(data, item) {
  const result = {};

  for (const key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result[key] = data[key].filter(obj => obj.node.title !== item);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const filteredData = removeItem(data, "Baja California License Plate Hat")
```

the gist

load in the object you want to update,
loop top level arrays,
look for entry where title matches,
filter that item out.

disclaimer untested.